# Flask crash: illegal hardware instruction

Tags: python, macos, flask, crash

This is a weird crash that I have no idea who has the responsibility for it. The crash only happens when running `flask` or `flask run`, but it's so good when running `python /usr/local/bin/flask [run]`.

I checked the installed `flask`, it's in

```
> type flask
> -rwxr-xr-x  1 thedev  admin   231B Apr  6  2017 /usr/local/bin/flask
```

It's a python file used the
script interpreter `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7`, the path is

```
> l /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 thedev  admin    57B May 13 15:32 /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -> ../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
> l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
> -rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin    25K Dec 18  2016 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

It seems it isn't a permission issue there, does someone know what the difference is?

Here is the crash stack:

```
Process:               Python [3724]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               2.7.13 (2.7.13)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [1913]
Responsible:           Python [3724]
User ID:               504

Date/Time:             2017-11-07 09:59:40.411 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx


Time Awake Since Boot: 330000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   org.python.python               0x0000000105c9bd2c PyTuple_New + 112
1   org.python.python               0x0000000105c9d70e PyType_Ready + 235
2   org.python.python               0x0000000105c9d6d0 PyType_Ready + 173
3   org.python.python               0x0000000105c8bdb7 _Py_ReadyTypes + 16
4   org.python.python               0x0000000105cf9550 Py_InitializeEx + 395
5   org.python.python               0x0000000105d0ba48 Py_Main + 1888
6   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffdefe0235 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000105d8763d  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x1e11cf0360d000da  rdx: 0x00000000000625eb
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x00007fff59fb9d60  rsp: 0x00007fff59fb9d50
   r8: 0x00007f948bc065e0   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0xffffffff00000000
  r12: 0x0000000105da3c90  r13: 0x0000000105d65ad0  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x00007f948bc06610
  rip: 0x0000000105c9bd2c  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000105d87680
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6


Binary Images:
       0x105c45000 -        0x105c46fff +org.python.python (2.7.13 - 2.7.13) <388F0305-67B0-3C97-8F12-7E7307941C3C> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x105c4e000 -        0x105d4aff7 +org.python.python (2.7.13, [c] 2001-2016 Python Software Foundation. - 2.7.13) <1EBB690C-E259-3912-83C2-4078C46F2ACF> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x107e5c000 -        0x107e99dc7  dyld (433.5) <322C06B7-8878-311D-888C-C8FD2CA96FF3> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fffc9391000 -     0x7fffc9824fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1349.8) <36385A3A-60D3-32DB-BF55-C6D8931A7AA6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fffdd783000 -     0x7fffdd784ff3  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (102) <84A04D24-0E60-3810-A8C0-90A65E2DF61A> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fffdd9c2000 -     0x7fffdd9c3ffb  libSystem.B.dylib (1238.60.2) <F18AC1E7-C6F1-34B1-8069-BE571B3231D4> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fffddb75000 -     0x7fffddbcbff7  libc++.1.dylib (307.5) <0B43BB5D-E6EB-3464-8DE9-B41AC8ED9D1C> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fffddbcc000 -     0x7fffddbf5ff7  libc++abi.dylib (307.4) <BC271AD3-831B-362A-9DA7-E8C51F285FE4> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fffde136000 -     0x7fffde35bffb  libicucore.A.dylib (57166.0.1) <CCD2ED24-3071-383B-925D-8D763BB12A6F> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fffde6ea000 -     0x7fffdeabfbc7  libobjc.A.dylib (709.1) <4DF3C25C-52C2-3F01-A3EF-0D9D53A73C1C> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fffdeee4000 -     0x7fffdeef5ff3  libz.1.dylib (67) <46E3FFA2-4328-327A-8D34-A03E20BFFB8E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fffdef04000 -     0x7fffdef08ff7  libcache.dylib (79) <093A4DAB-8385-3D47-A350-E20CB7CCF7BF> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fffdef09000 -     0x7fffdef13fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60092.50.5) <8A64D1B0-C70E-385C-92F0-E669079FDA90> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fffdef14000 -     0x7fffdef1bfff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (62) <55D47421-772A-32AB-B529-1A46C2F43B4D> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fffdef1c000 -     0x7fffdef24fff  libcopyfile.dylib (138) <819BEA3C-DF11-3E3D-A1A1-5A51C5BF1961> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fffdef25000 -     0x7fffdefa8fdf  libcorecrypto.dylib (442.50.19) <65D7165E-2E71-335D-A2D6-33F78E2DF0C1> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fffdefa9000 -     0x7fffdefdafff  libdispatch.dylib (703.50.37) <6582BAD6-ED27-3B30-B620-90B1C5A4AE3C> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fffdefdb000 -     0x7fffdefe0ffb  libdyld.dylib (433.5) <9B2AC56D-107C-3541-A127-9094A751F2C9> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fffdefe1000 -     0x7fffdefe1ffb  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <7AA011A9-DC21-3488-BF73-3B5B14D1FDD6> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fffdefef000 -     0x7fffdefeffff  liblaunch.dylib (972.70.1) <B856ABD2-896E-3DE0-B2C8-146A6AF8E2A7> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fffdeff0000 -     0x7fffdeff5ff3  libmacho.dylib (898) <17D5D855-F6C3-3B04-B680-E9BF02EF8AED> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fffdeff6000 -     0x7fffdeff8ff3  libquarantine.dylib (85.50.1) <12448CC2-378E-35F3-BE33-9DC395A5B970> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fffdeff9000 -     0x7fffdeffaffb  libremovefile.dylib (45) <38D4CB9C-10CD-30D3-8B7B-A515EC75FE85> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fffdeffb000 -     0x7fffdf013ff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (349.50.5) <096E4228-3B7C-30A6-8B13-EC909A64499A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fffdf014000 -     0x7fffdf014ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (67) <10DC5404-73AB-35B3-A277-A8AFECB476EB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fffdf015000 -     0x7fffdf0a2fef  libsystem_c.dylib (1158.50.2) <E5AE5244-7D0C-36AC-8BB6-C7AE7EA52A4B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fffdf0a3000 -     0x7fffdf0a6ffb  libsystem_configuration.dylib (888.60.2) <BECC01A2-CA8D-31E6-BCDF-D452965FA976> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fffdf0a7000 -     0x7fffdf0aafff  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (41.4) <7D26DE79-B424-3450-85E1-F7FAB32714AB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fffdf0ab000 -     0x7fffdf0c3fff  libsystem_coretls.dylib (121.50.4) <EC6FCF07-DCFB-3A03-9CC9-6DD3709974C6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x7fffdf0c4000 -     0x7fffdf0cafff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (765.50.9) <CC960215-0B1B-3822-A13A-3DDE96FA796F> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fffdf0cb000 -     0x7fffdf0f4ff7  libsystem_info.dylib (503.50.4) <611DB84C-BF70-3F92-8702-B9F28A900920> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fffdf0f5000 -     0x7fffdf117ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (3789.70.16) <34B1F16C-BC9C-3C5F-9045-0CAE91CB5914> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fffdf118000 -     0x7fffdf15ffe7  libsystem_m.dylib (3121.6) <86D499B5-BBDC-3D3B-8A4E-97AE8E6672A4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fffdf160000 -     0x7fffdf17eff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (116.50.8) <A3D15F17-99A6-3367-8C7E-4280E8619C95> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fffdf17f000 -     0x7fffdf1d8ffb  libsystem_network.dylib (856.60.1) <369D0221-56CA-3C3E-9EDE-94B41CAE77B7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fffdf1d9000 -     0x7fffdf1e2ff3  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (563.60.2) <B021F2B3-8A75-3633-ABB0-FC012B8E9B0C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fffdf1e3000 -     0x7fffdf1ecff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (165.20.1) <B8160190-A069-3B3A-BDF6-2AA408221FAE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fffdf1ed000 -     0x7fffdf1f5fe7  libsystem_platform.dylib (126.50.8) <897462FD-B318-321B-A554-E61982630F7E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fffdf1f6000 -     0x7fffdf200ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (218.60.3) <B8FB5E20-3295-39E2-B5EB-B464D1D4B104> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fffdf201000 -     0x7fffdf204ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (592.70.1) <4B92EC49-ACD0-36AE-B07A-A2B8152EAF9D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fffdf205000 -     0x7fffdf206ff3  libsystem_secinit.dylib (24.50.4) <F78B847B-3565-3E4B-98A6-F7AD40392E2D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fffdf207000 -     0x7fffdf20effb  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (532.50.47) <3390E07C-C1CE-348F-ADBD-2C5440B45EAA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
    0x7fffdf20f000 -     0x7fffdf222ff7  libsystem_trace.dylib (518.70.1) <AC63A7FE-50D9-3A30-96E6-F6B7FF16E465> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fffdf223000 -     0x7fffdf228ffb  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <3D50D8A8-C460-334D-A519-2DA841102C6B> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fffdf229000 -     0x7fffdf252ff7  libxpc.dylib (972.70.1) <BF896DF0-D8E9-31A8-A4B3-01120BFEEE52> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 316143
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 1675

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=130.4M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=130.4M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=17.5M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=17.5M(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
MALLOC                            9396K        8 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        2 
Stack                             8192K        2 
__DATA                            3264K       49 
__LINKEDIT                       114.8M        5 
__TEXT                            15.6M       46 
__UNICODE                          556K        2 
shared memory                        8K        3 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            207.3M      113 

Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B18, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.8 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.130.1a1)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.5f1, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Apple USB Ethernet, Ethernet, en4
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Network Service: iPhone USB, Ethernet, en5
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD256E, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub
USB Device: Apple USB Ethe娕燬ጠ✩退骞ꢧЉ≠㙱นн
USB Device: USB Gaming Keyboard
USB Device: USB Optical Mouse
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Wireless Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```